# $f$ is convex if and only if $f =\sup\{\varphi:\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}: \varphi \le f, \varphi \text { affine} \}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis

**Let $f : \mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R} $

$f$ is convex if and only if $f =\sup\{\varphi:\mathbb{R}^M\to \mathbb{R}: \varphi \le f, \varphi  \text { affine} \}$**

I am having trouble proving ($\implies$)

**To prove it I have to follow the following hints:**

1)Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}^M$ , and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $t < f (x)$ We claim that there exists an affine function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\varphi \le f$ such that $\varphi(x) > t$; For this:

1a) Consider the point $P := (x, t)$. Prove that there exists a point $Q$ which minimizes the distance from $P$ to the graph of $f$

1b)Define the function $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^M \to \mathbb{R}$ as the affine function whose graph is the tangent plane to $\partial  B(P, |P − Q|)$ and passing by  $Q$

1c) Prove that $\varphi \le f$ Assume by contradiction that there exists a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^M$ such that $f (y) < \varphi(y)$. Let $A := (y, f (y))$. Prove that there exists a point $E$ on the graph of $f$ which is inside $B(P, |P − Q|)$. contradicting the choice of $Q$

---

**My try:**
I have worked out some of my ideas for each part , but I am missing pieces to complete it

1a) This one I almost have it.  Define the graph of $f$ as: $Graph (f)=\{(x,f(x)):x \in dom f\}$
and the epigraph: $Ep (f)=\{(x,y):x \in dom f , y>f(x)\}$, which is convex because $f$ is convex. Ep(f) is also a closed set, and non-empty. Since we are in a Hilbert space and these are the hypotheses of Hilbert's projection theorem, I can conclude that there exists a point $Q\in Ep(f)$ such that the distance from $P$ to the set $Ep(f)$ is minimized.

**Now, I am missing the fact that this point should be in the graph, not in the epigraph Ep(f), how do I conclude that? It is kind of intuitive that points in the interior are further, but how would I formalize it? Maybe Hilbert's theorem is not the way to go then?**

1b) The equation of $\varphi$ as described in the hint should be $\varphi (y)= a \cdot y+a_0$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}^M$  and $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. I am not sure if this way of writting it is convenient, because it is not clear by just looking at the equation that it passes by $Q$ and that the normal vector is $Q-P$.  Maybe  a vector form is better: $n \cdot (R-Q)=(Q-P) \cdot (R-Q)=0, $ for all $R\in \mathbb{R}^{M+1}$ .**The problem is that this equation is implicit, I don't see the function as in the cartesian form**

1c) Proceding as in the hint:
Assume by contradiction that there exists a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^M$ such that $f (y) < \varphi(y)$. Let $A := (y, f (y))$. Let $Q=(y_q,f(y_q))$ and let $E=(y,\varphi(y))$ (Which I claim is the point I am looking for)
So I need to show that this point is inside $B(P, |P − Q|)$, namely that $|E-P|<|P-Q| $. I have tried to use the triangle inequality in many ways but I don't find what I need, for instance

$|P-E|\le |P-Q|+|Q-A|+|A-E|=|P-Q|+|Q-A|+|f(y)-\varphi(y)|$

In this way  $f(y)-\varphi(y)$ shows up, which should be non zero because of the hypothesis, but **I don't know how to continue**

Comment: I have a proof that does not follow the hints provided, but which relies on the Hanh-Banach separation theorem. Would you be interested?

Comment: @Didier Although I hope someone can help me with this approach, that would be welcome as an side thing!

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This proof does not follow the hints provided by OP.
Let us first show a general Lemma.

> Lemma: Let $\mathcal{F} \subset \{\varphi \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R\}$ be a set of convex functions such that $\sup_{\varphi \in \mathcal{F}}\varphi(x) < + \infty$ for all $x\in \Bbb R^n$.
> Then $f(x) := \sup_{\varphi \in \mathcal{F}} \varphi(x)$ defines a convex function.

*Proof:*
Fix $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$ and $t\in [0,1]$.
Let $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}$.
For $\varphi$ is convex, one has
$
\varphi((1-t)x+ty) \leqslant (1-t)\varphi(x)+t\varphi(y).
$
Taking the suppremum of the right hand side over $\varphi\in \mathcal{F}$ then yields
$$
\forall \varphi \in \mathcal{F},\quad \varphi((1-t)x+ty) \leqslant (1-t)f(x) + tf(y),
$$
and now taking the supremum over $\varphi$ on the left hand side yields
$$
f((1-t)x+ty) \leqslant (1-t)f(x)+tf(y).
$$
This shows that $f$ is convex. $\blacksquare$

Let's now go back to the original question.

Assume that $f$ is such that $f = \sup\{\varphi \mid f \geqslant \varphi ,~ \varphi \text{ affine}\}$.
For affine functions are convex, the above Lemma implies that $f$ is convex.

Conversely, assume that $f$ is convex.
Let $\mathcal{F} = \{ \varphi \text{ affine} \mid \varphi \leqslant f\}$, and $\bar{f} = \sup_{\varphi\in \mathcal{F}} \varphi\leqslant f$.
We want to show that $\bar{f} = f$.
To do so, one only needs to show that for any $x_0\in \Bbb R^n$, there exists $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}$ with $\varphi(x_0) = f(x_0)$.
Indeed, we would have $f(x_0)=\varphi(x_0) \leqslant \bar{f}(x_0)\leqslant f(x_0)$.
Let us fix $x_0\in \Bbb R^n$.

Let $C = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R \mid y> f(x)\}$, which is the interior of the epigraph of $f$, and $K  = \{(x_0,f(x_0))\}$.
Then $C$ is open, $K$ is compact, both are convex, and they are disjoint.
By (one of the many versions of) Hanh-Banach separation Theorem, there exists a non-zero linear function $\psi\colon \Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ such that
$$
\label{eq1}
\tag{$\star$}
\sup_K \psi \leqslant \inf_C \psi.
$$
Let $\phi \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ and $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ be the unique linear function and real number such that
$$
\forall (x,y) \in \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R,\quad \psi(x,y) = \phi(x) + \alpha y.
$$
Then \eqref{eq1} reads
$$
\label{eq2}
\tag{$\star\star$}
\forall (x,y) \in C,\quad \phi(x_0) + \alpha f(x_0) \leqslant \phi(x) + \alpha y.
$$
One first deduces, setting $x = x_0$ in \eqref{eq2}, and since $f(x_0) < y$, that $\alpha >0$ (note that $\alpha = 0$ is not possible, as it would lead to $\phi=0$).
Now, for any $x$, taking $y \to f(x)$, one obtains
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb R^n,\quad \phi(x_0) + \alpha f(x_0) \leqslant \phi(x) + \alpha f(x).
$$
This latter can be rephrased, since $\alpha >0$, as
$$
\forall x \in \Bbb R^n, \quad \frac{1}{\alpha}\phi(x_0-x) + f(x_0) \leqslant f(x).
$$
The affine map $\varphi\colon x \mapsto \frac{1}{\alpha}\phi(x_0-x)+f(x_0)$ is then in $\mathcal{F}$, and $\varphi(x_0) = f(x_0)$.
This concludes the proof.